# Terminal object in vector spaces with two fixed points (solution verification)

Tags: category-theory, solution-verification

I am looking for solution verification for a rather basic category theory problem.

Observe a category where:

- objects are triples $(V, v_1, v_2)$ where $V$ is a vector space and $v_1, v_2 \in V$ are distinct vectors
- morphisms $(U, u_1, u_2) \rightarrow (V, v_1, v_2)$ are linear maps $L : U \rightarrow V$ such that $L(u_1)=v_1$ and $L(u_2)=v_2$.

The task is to find the **initial** and **terminal** objects in this category.

I worked out that $(V, v_1, v_2)$ is initial iff $V$ is two-dimensional and $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent. This works since a linear map $L: (V, v_1, v_2) \rightarrow (X, x_1, x_2)$ given by its values on basis $v_1, v_2$ is unique.

I think that there is no terminal object in this category. Consider an arbitrary object $(V, v_1, v_2)$.  If $v_2 = \alpha v_1$ then there are no morphisms $(U, u_1, \beta u_1) \rightarrow (V, v_1, \alpha v_1)$ if $\beta \neq \alpha$, since $L(\beta u_1) = \beta L(u_1) = \beta v_1 \neq \alpha v_1$ (note that $v_1\neq 0$ since $v_1 \neq \alpha v_1$ by object definition). If though $v_1, v_2$ are linearly independent, then again a morphism $(U, u_1, \beta u_1) \rightarrow (V, v_1, v_2)$ would immediately imply $L(\beta u_1) = \beta v_1 = v_2$, which is not the case.

I am not sure about my solution only because the problem states "to find" the object and not to prove the contrary... Also I'd be interested in other approaches, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forgetful functor is representable in this category. Therefore the underlying set of the terminal object, if it exists, must be a 1-element set. This contradicts the requirement that the two chosen elements be distinct.